# Node websocket server on Ubuntu Core

Tags: ubuntu-core, nodejs

My goal is to run a node.js server on Ubuntu Core on RPI. I'm using websockets and those are supposed to be imported and installed with npm. Does anyone have any experience running node no Core and are there any implications that might prevent me from doing so?